# different behavior of reduce method

Tags: python, lambda

I had a list of numbers. I wanted to calculate the bitwise `and` of some subset of the list. I used the `reduce` method. I thought these two methods should yield the same result.

```
table = [5, 10, 2, 6, 7, 18, 19, 1, 4, 9, 17, 8, 16, 0, 15, 11, 12, 13, 3, 14]
l = [0,1,2,3]
print reduce (lambda x,y:table[x]&table[y] , l ) 
print reduce (lambda x,y:x&y , [ table[x] for x in l ] )
```

But After lots of debugging I noticed they don't. I don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Hint: After the first calculation `x` contains the result of the previous calculation not the index from `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood what `reduce()` does. It calls the `lambda` with the *result of the previous call* and the next value from the list. If there was no previous value, the first element of the list is used instead.

As such, `x` is going to be the previous outcome each time, except for the first time. It is **not** going to be `table[x]` from your list comprehension, nor is it going to be a value from the list when not using a list comprehension.

For your first `reduce()` call then, this happens:

- `x` is set to `0`, `y` to `1`. `table[0] & table[1]` is calculated, making `5 & 10`, outcome is `0`.
- `x` is thus set to `0` (previous result) and `y` is set to the next value in `l`, so `2`. `table[0] & table[2]` is calculated, making `5 & 2`, outcome is again `0`.
- `x` is thus set to `0` (previous result) and `y` is set to the next value in `l`, so `3`. `table[0] & table[3]` is calculated, making `5 & 6`, outcome is now `4`.

Your second `reduce()` call is given values directly from `table`, so you now use `[5, 10, 2, 6]` as the input and no longer consult `table` when reducing:

- `x` is set to `5`, `y` is set to `10`. `5 & 10` makes `0`
- `x` is thus set to `0` (previous result) and `y` is set to the next value in the list, so `2`. `0 & 2` is calculated, outcome is again `0`.
- `x` is thus set to `0` (previous result) and `y` is set to the next value in the list, so `6`. `0 & 6` is calculated, outcome is again `0`.

The difference then is that you misunderstood what `table[x]` value is picked.

Because `reduce()` applies the call to the previous result each time, you should really see it like a chained set of calls. Your first `reduce()` can be written out to:

```
table[table[table[0] & table[1]] & table[2]] & table[3]
```

while your second `reduce()` effectively calculates:

```
((table[0] & table[1]) & table[2]) & table[3]
```

Comment: For visual proof of this concept run your code [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to understand reduce() is to look at its pure Python equivalent code:

```
def myreduce(func, iterable, start=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if start is None:
        try:
            start = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = start
    for x in iterable:
        accum_value = func(accum_value, x)
    return accum_value
```

You can see that it only makes sense for your reduce_func() to apply the factorial to the rightmost argument:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return fact(n-1) * n

def reduce_func(x,y):
    return x * fact(y)

lst = [1, 3, 1]
print reduce(reduce_func, lst)
```